# AngularJs ,ngSanitize and ngRoute don't work together

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute, ngsanitize

I have a question about ngRoute.If when I wrote as follows there is not a problem

index.html

```
<div ng-app="linkyDemo">
<div ng-controller="Ctrl" ng-bind-html="text| linky"></div></div>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize'])
function Ctrl($scope) {
$scope.text= 'http://absdef.com';
}
```

But when I use ngRoute directive like as

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'ngSanitize']);
```

linky filter doesn't work. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you using the latest version/s?

Comment: I 'm using angularjs 1.2.25

Comment: 1.2.25 was released in September 2014 - you should upgrade to the latest version. Are you sure you have all the necessary scripts referenced in your HTML index: ng-route.js, ng-sanitize.js etc?

Comment: When I was using angular 1.2.25  both of them had worked without any problem,but they didn.'t work together.  Now, after ugrading neither ngRoute or ngSanitize work

Comment: what exactly did you upgrade and to which versions?

Comment: I tried this version https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js

Comment: If I were you, I would scaffold a new app with yeoman, and work from that. https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular 

More than likely to work out of the box, with the latest versions of everything. You will save yourself trying to find out why X version isn't working with Y version and so on.